# Create folder on FTP server with PHP

Tags: php, ftp, backend, php-7.1, ftp-server

I use `Current PHP version: 7.1.4` for `Ionic2` application back-end.

I'm trying to create folder on my `ftp server`. With direct link to php file `http://site/php/directory.php` echo is

> Successfully created images

After this, folder `images` does not exist in directory, and with second link to php, message is:

> Warning: ftp_mkdir(): Can't create directory: File exists in
>   /path/php/directory.php on line 8 Error while creating images

but folder `images` was not created and does not exist in directory. Then I've manually created a folder `images` with FTP client tool, this way folder was really created as usually.

Why with first link to `http://site/php/directory.php` echo was  `Successfully created images` and with second  `Can't create directory: File exists in` if folder `images` was not created, and after this, also I was able to create the folder `images` manually. I'm not sure, maybe it is some specific default server setting, or some kind of hidden folder. I do not have hidden files there, so no idea what is wrong here:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp_address";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "ftp_username", "ftp_password");

$dir = "images";

if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $dir))
  {
  echo "Successfully created $dir";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error while creating $dir";
  }
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you expect the folder to be created? Where do you check for it in your "FTP client tool"?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Hello, this question is answered by misanthrop by content, but does not answers to my problem.  I have to mark this answer, and create new question, which describes problem, and where I want create folder here: [Create folder on FTP server in specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899803/create-folder-on-ftp-server-in-specific-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder was created but on a different location. You have to look up where your php code is actually executed and then you will find the wrongly created folder.

From my point of view: its quite tricky to define where such a folder or file gets created. There are however "show working directory" commands which will help you out debugging this.

Comment: Hello, I have to mark your answer, because it is answers to my question by content,  but does not answers to my problem.  I have to create new question, which describes problem here: [Create folder on FTP server in specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899803/create-folder-on-ftp-server-in-specific-directory)