# Create folder on FTP server in directory where PHP script is

Tags: php, ftp, backend, php-7.1, ftp-server

I use `Current PHP version: 7.1.4` for `Ionic2` application back-end.

I'm trying to create folder on my `ftp server` in the same directory, where `directory.php` located itself.

After link to `http://site/php/directory.php` echo:

> Successfully created images

it creates `images` folder in **user** directory:

> home/**user**/public_html/folder/php/uploads/

My `directory.php` located in `php` folder:

> home/user/public_html/folder/**php**/uploads/

I want create `images` directory in exist `uploads` folder:

> home/user/public_html/folder/php/**uploads**/`images`

uploads folder allows to create folder manually with FTP client tool

So what  I have to do, to create it in `uploads` directory:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp_address";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "ftp_username", "ftp_password");

$dir = "images";

if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $dir))
  {
  echo "Successfully created $dir";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error while creating $dir";
  }
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a directory *on the web server*, the directory is *local* in a context of the PHP script. So do not use FTP functions, use functions for a local file system. Namely [`mkdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

```
<?
$dir = "images";
if (mkdir($dir))
{
    echo "Successfully created $dir";
}
else
{
    echo "Error while creating $dir";
}
```

Most web servers execute PHP script with its actual location as a working directory. So a relative path like `image` will resolve relatively to a path of your PHP script.